# Sometimes you can't view hat details

Tags: bug, profile-page, per-site-meta, winter-bash

The title says it all. Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on a user with any hat. It needs to be from a [per-site-meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12708583/10-rep); it's no-repro here.
2. When in their profile, click on their hat on their profile picture.
3. The page will simply reload, so go to their main user and click on it again.
4. You can click on a hat, but it won't give you details about the hat.

Here is a gif demonstrating the behavior:

> [image]

Comment: It's nothing to do with it being a user you've never visited. Clicking the hat link _from meta_ simply doesn't work correctly. You also don't need to click on the hat in their profile, clicking their profile picture simply reloads their profile. All you need to do is navigate to any account on meta, click Activity, click their hats.

Comment: @Nick but why doesn't it work. Isn't that a bug? NVM I assumed otherwise.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't